# Trying to install Ubuntu on a Macbook with a new hard drive and no OSX

Tags: startup

The hard drive of my Macbook failed recently. After installing a new hard drive I would like to use Ubuntu as the operating system, not Mac OS x. I burned a Ubuntu .iso to a disc and when I power up and insert the disc into the slot, I still get the flashing question marks folder.

The macbook is macbook core duo, I think it was originally purchased in 2006 or 2007. The hard drive is completely blank and the only file on the DVD disc is the most current version of Ubuntu.

How can I get the macbook to read the dvd?

Comment: If the .iso is a file on the DVD, something went wrong during the burning. The .iso contains the full image and should be dumped to the DVD in full. If this is not the issue, did you try starting the Mac with the Alt/Opt key pressed?

Comment: I tried holding the option key. It gave me a mouse cursor, which is different from the question mark, but it still isn't giving me anything to really work with.

Comment: How and where did you burn the DVD?

Comment: Using windows 7 on a different laptop. I downloaded the ubuntu 32 bit off of the website this morning and burned the .iso to a dvd. Should I use a different utility?

Comment: If you put the DVD back into the PC, do you see one big ubuntu.iso file or something else?

Comment: it says ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso and thats it.

I tried testing it by booting the file from my windows computer (holding F12 at startup, highlighting boot from CD) and nothing happened. It went straight to windows7. I think you are right about the iso not being burned correctly.